# How can I pass parameters to a Lua file when loading it from another Lua file?

Tags: lua

I need some help on parsing the Command Line for a lua file. I am executing a lua file and that lua file has a command "dofile(2nd.lua-file)", but, I want to pass some argument to this 2nd lua file through this 1st lua file.

example-
a.lua has dofile("b.lua"), and now I have to pass some argument to b.lua through this a.lua and how can I do this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this. In file `a.lua':

`assert(loadfile("b.lua"))(10,20,30)`

In file `b.lua`:

`local a,b,c=...`

or

`local arg={...}`

The arguments to `b.lua` are received as varargs, hence the `...`.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I run it with dofile(b.lua)(10), 
I get "unexpected symbol near '.'" and my b.lua as the following local a=.

Comment: @Invictus, it's three dots `...` as posted. That's the Lua syntax for varargs. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way:

Command and output:

```
C:\LUAWORK\Estudio-Tut>lua -e "a=2 b=3 c=4 dofile(‘argu.lua’)"
```

> 2 3 4
>
> 4 6 8

File 1, argu.lua:

```
print (a , b ,c)
a=2*a
b=2*b
c=2*c
dofile ( ‘otro.lua’)
```

File 2, otro.lua:

```
print (a ,b, c)
```

Using  -e "……." I set globals in the call to any chain of modules