# How can I pass the arguments to the lua file through the lua CLI

Tags: lua, command-line-interface

I have a LUA CLI which takes in the lua command,

Something like this 
(lua)> #

Now here inorder to execute the lua file I run the command

(lua)> # dofile("a.lua")

I want a command which will execute the file and also pass a argument to it.

Now here I want to pass a argument to the "a.lua" file which will take this argument and call one more lua file, and this 2nd lua file is called according to the argument, So, I need to parse this argument.

Please, can somebody tell me about the parsing commands that will be used in a.lua. I mean what are the functions to be used to parse it.

Please, can somebody tell me how to pass a argument to this file "a.lua".

Comment: Very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744693/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-lua-file-when-loading-it-from-another-lua-file if not a duplicate...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Now here inorder to execute the lua file I run the command

This is generally not how you execute Lua files. Usually, if you have some Lua script, you execute it with this command: `lua a.lua`. You don't type `lua` and then use the interface there to execute it.

Using a proper command line to execute the script, you can pass string parameters to the file: `lua a.lua someParam "Param with spaces"`. The `a.lua` script can then fetch these parameters using the standard Lua `...` mechanic:

```
local params = {...}
params[1] -- first parameter, if any.
params[2] -- second parameter, if any.
#params   -- number of parameters.
```

However, if you insist on trying to execute this using your method of invoking the interpreter (with `lua`) and typing commands into it one by one, then you can do this:

```
> GlobalVariable = assert(loadfile(`a.lua`))
> GlobalVariable(--[[Insert parameters here]])
```

However, if you don't want to do it in two steps, with the intermediate global variable, you can do it in one:

```
> assert(loadfile(`a.lua`))(--[[Insert parameters here]])
```