# lua - loadfile is executing right away and i can't figure out why

Tags: lua

I was under the impression that doing something like this:

```
local f = assert (loadfile('/var/www/widgets/widgetlookup.lua'))('13')
```

would just load the contents of widgetlookup.lua into the variable "f" and then to run the code, i could do this:

```
 f()
```

However, what's happening is that as soon as I load the file, it's executing.  I know because widgetlookup.lua prints out a string with the results. Ultimately, I need to capture the results of the script in a variable

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?  If you need to see the contents of widgetlookup.lua please just say the word and i will post.  Just didn't want to clutter up the question with unnecessary information.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I changed my code to look like this:

```
local f = assert (loadfile('/var/www/widgets/widgetlookup.lua'))
local p = f(13)
```

And now code waits to run until i hit the second line... but I need to know how to capture the output of the script as a variable....

print(p) current returns a null value.

Comment: _"but I need to know how to capture the output of the script as a variable...."_ What output? What the script returns? What it prints? Please be specific.

Comment: You should also make a new SO question if you have a new question

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo sorry for being ambiguous.  Yes, the widgetlookup.lua script returns a string.  I believe i included this comment in my post but hopefully this clarifies things

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it with that `('13')` at the end.

You want this:

```
local f = assert (loadfile('/var/www/widgets/widgetlookup.lua'))
```

Comment: i need the 13 becuase the widgetlookup.lua file takes parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744693/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-lua-file-when-loading-it-from-another-lua-file