# What is "object = {...}" in lua good for?

Tags: lua

I recently read about lua and addons for the game "World of Warcraft". Since the interface language for addons is lua and I want to learn a new language, I thought this was a good idea.

But there is this one thing I can't get to know. In almost every addon there is this line on the top which looks for me like a constructor that creates a object on which member I can have access to. This line goes something like this:

```
object = {...}
```

I know that if a function returns several values (which is IMHO one huge plus for lua) and I don't want to store them seperatly in several values, I can just write

```
myArray = {SomeFunction()}
```

where `myArray` is now a table that contains the values and I can access the values by indexing it (`myArray[4]`). Since the elements are not explicitly typed because only the values themselfe hold their type, this is fine for lua. I also know that "..." can be used for a parameter array in a function for the case that the function does not know how many parameter it gets when called (like `String[] args` in java). But what in gods name is this "curly bracket - dot, dot, dot - curly bracket" used for???

Comment: In a function, like this: `function x(...) object = {...} end`, this is essentially the type of operation as `myArray = {SomeFunction()}`, only it stuffs the parameters into a table and stores that table in `object`.

Comment: I don't know what the triple dot syntax means outside of a function. Perhaps addons are loaded as sort of a call, and thus have some form of context parameters?

Comment: You can have a look at "Questie" on github (https://github.com/AeroScripts/QuestieDev). In the Questie.lua and modules/QuestieAuto.loa you have _Questie = {...} and QuestieAuto_Questie = {...}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already said all there is to it in your question:

`{...}` is really just a combination of the two behaviors you described: It creates a table containing all the arguments, so

```lua
function foo(a, b, ...)
   return {...}
end

foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) --> {3, 4, 5}
```

Basically, `...` is just a normal expression, just like a function call that returns multiple values. The following two expressions work in the exact same way:

```
local a, b, c = ...
local d, e, f = some_function()
```

Keep in mind though that this has some performance implications, so maybe don't use it in a function that gets called like 1000 times a second ;)

---

EDIT:

Note that this really doesn't apply just to "functions". Functions are actually more of a syntax feature than anything else. Under the hood, Lua only knows of chunks, which are what both functions and `.lua` files get turned into. So, if you run a Lua script, the entire script gets turned into a chunk and is therefore no different than a function.

In terms of code, the difference is that with a function you can specify names for its arguments outside of its code, whereas with a file you're already at the outermost level of code; there's no "outside" a file.

Luckily, all Lua files, when they're loaded as a chunk, are automatically variadic, meaning they get the `...` to access their argument list.

When you call a file like `lua script.lua foo bar`, inside script.lua, `...` will actually contain the two arguments "foo" and "bar", so that's also a convenient way to access arguments when using Lua for standalone scripts.

In your example, it's actually quite similar. Most likely, somewhere else your script gets loaded with `load()`, which returns a function that you can call—and, you guessed it, pass arguments to.

Imagine the following situation:

```lua
function foo(a, b)
   print(b)
   print(a)
end

foo('hello', 'world')
```

This is almost equivalent to

```lua
function foo(...)
   local a, b = ...
   print(b)
   print(a)
end

foo('hello', 'world')
```

Which is 100% (Except maybe in performance) equivalent to

```lua
-- Note that [[ string ]] is just a convenient syntax for multiline "strings"
foo = load([[
   local a, b = ...
   print(b)
   print(a)
]])

foo('hello', 'world')
```

Comment: In the case of WoW addons (see hiw comment about the Questie addon), this construct is used at the top level of the addon, *outside* of the functions declared in the addon. However, there may be some context being passed from the game to the addon which would fit in this. Not sure what that would be though.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I extended my answer a bit to clarify

Answer (score 2):

From the [Lua 5.1 Reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html) then {...} means the arguments passed to the program. In your case those are probably the arguments passed from the game to the addon.

You can see references to this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744693/how-can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-lua-file-when-loading-it-from-another-lua-file) and [this thread](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/27480-meaning-of-three-dots/).

Answer (score 1):

Put the following text at the start of the file:

```
local args = {...}
for __, arg in ipairs(args) do
    print(arg)
end
```

And it reveals that:

- args[1] is the name of the addon
- args[2] is a (empty) table passed by reference to all files in the same addon

Information inserted to args[2] is therefore available to different files.